# Android Camera Example - Not Saving Image

Tags: android, bitmap, android-camera

I'm currently trying to implement the Camera within my app to take a full image and save it. I'm following the guide at [android.com](http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html) under the 'Save the Full-Size Photo' section.

The first part of that tutorial worked without a problem, but it seems to simply not save the full image for some reason. When using the setPic function, it will crash as the Bitmap it gets has a size of 0. The addGalleryPic function doesn't seem to add anything to the gallery either.

Thanks for your help!

Manifiest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Activity:

```
String mCurrentPhotoPath;
static final int REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO = 1;
```

Creating the file.

```
private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);

    File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",         /* suffix */
            storageDir      /* directory */
    );

    // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
    mCurrentPhotoPath = "file:" + image.getAbsolutePath();
    return image;
}
```

Opening the Camera intent.

```
private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        // Create the File where the photo should go
        File photoFile = null;
        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // Error occurred while creating the File

        }
        // Continue only if the File was successfully created
        if (photoFile != null) {
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                    Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
        }
    }
}
```

Overriding the Activity Result.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Logger.d( "onResult: " + requestCode + " & " + resultCode  );
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        Logger.d( "Attempting to open: " + mCurrentPhotoPath );
        galleryAddPic();
        setPic();
    }
}
```

Adding the image to the gallery.

```
private void galleryAddPic() {
    Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
    File f = new File(mCurrentPhotoPath);
    Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
    mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
    this.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
}
```

And setting the image to the imageView.

```
private void setPic() {
    // Get the dimensions of the View
    int targetW = image.getWidth();
    int targetH = image.getHeight();

    // Get the dimensions of the bitmap
    BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath, bmOptions);
    int photoW = bmOptions.outWidth;
    int photoH = bmOptions.outHeight;


    // Both of these values are zero.
    Logger.d( "Size: " + photoW + "x" + photoH );

    // Determine how much to scale down the image
    // **THIS LINE CRASHES - Divide by zero ( size is zero ).**
    int scaleFactor = Math.min(photoW/targetW, photoH/targetH);

    // Decode the image file into a Bitmap sized to fill the View
    bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    bmOptions.inSampleSize = scaleFactor;
    bmOptions.inPurgeable = true;

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath, bmOptions);
    image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}
```

Comment: "it seems to simply not save the full image" -- please explain **precisely** what your symptoms are. Are you crashing? Are you getting the image in the `ImageView`? If you are not seeing the file, how are you trying to find the file (desktop OS file manager? DDMS? `adb`? something else?).

Comment: Using setPic() will crash as it tries to divide by zero (photoW/targetW), the line after my Logger prints out the size.

I've tried looking onto my actual device and can't find any files.

I'm not too sure what else I could do to try to find where Android is putting the image, or how it's trying to find it. Also using the galleryAddPic() function doesn't actually add anything to my gallery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend that you get rid of `String mCurrentPhotoPath` and replace it with `File mCurrentPhoto` (or another name as you see fit). This will clear up a few bugs:

- `mCurrentPhotoPath = "file:" + image.getAbsolutePath();` results in a value that is neither a valid filesystem path nor a valid string representation of a `Uri`
- `File f = new File(mCurrentPhotoPath);` results in an invalid `File`, because of the rogue `file:` you are putting on the filesystem path in the above bullet
- `BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath, bmOptions);` will not work, because of the rogue `file:` you are putting on the filesystem path in the first bullet

Most of the time, you are using the `File` anyway. And then for `decodeFile()`, just call `getAbsolutePath()` at that point (`BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhoto.getAbsolutePath(), bmOptions)`).

Comment: I made those changes and it fixes most of my problems, thank you! The image now saves correctly and I can see it within my storage, and get it back with BitmapFactory.decodeFile. 
Although, the galleryAddPic() function doesn't seem to add it to my gallery, so I can't see it within my Photos app.

And for some reason, the imageView.getWidth() still returns 0, so if I don't try to scale by it does show up correctly.

Comment: @Awestruck: "Although, the galleryAddPic() function doesn't seem to add it to my gallery, so I can't see it within my Photos app" -- I use `MediaScannerConnection` and its static `scanFile()` method, personally. "the imageView.getWidth() still returns 0" -- are you sure that the `ImageView` has been laid out by the time this code runs? And, are you giving the `ImageView` an explicit size, or are you using `wrap_content` for the dimensions?